# OrchardCMS: how to pick a user from content picker

Tags: orchardcms

I add a contentpicker field to my License content type and wish to be able to assign some users to this content item.

I can select other content items expect Users from ContentPicker when I create a new License.

How can I select a specified user in ContentPicker?

Thanks

Comment: @Sid Try to add Common part and Title part to User content type. But there is no help. And even more, when the Common part is added to User content type, it crashes the IIS application pool.....

Comment: This is a known issue, see [this github issue](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/1326) for reference